# Integer solution to system of equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The problem is finding positive integer solutions to the system of equations
$$x+y-z=12$$
$$x^3+y^3-z^2=2022$$

I tried to modding the equation by 2,3,5, but I do not see a pattern. Then I used computer to find that the solution should be $x=7,y=12,z=7$, so is there a way of showing that $x=z$?

Thanks

Comment: I think, you assume $x\le y$ because we can swap $x$ and $y$ to get another solution.

Comment: There is no way of showing that $x=z$ because it might not be true. For example, $x=12, y=7, z=7$ is a solution where $x\neq z$.

Comment: Your solution could be the only one (if we WLOG assume $x\le y$) : for $x,y\le 10^5$ , there is no other. I have however no idea how this can be proven. And without such a proof, it will be difficult to show that $x$ with this assumption must be equal to $z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x+y-z=12\tag 1$$
$$x^3+y^3-z^2=2022\tag2$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ can be transformed to
$$x+y=z+12\tag3$$
$$(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)=z^2+2022\tag4$$
if we substitute $x+y$ by $12+z$ in $(4)$, we get
$$(12+z)((12+z)^2-3xy)=z^2+2022\tag{5}$$
and further
$$3xy=(12+z)^2-\frac{2022+z^2}{12+z}\tag{6}$$
Calculating the fractions gives

$$3xy=(12+z)^2+(12-z)-\frac{2166}{12+z}\tag{7}$$

so $12+z$ must be a divisor of $2166$.
So you have only finitely many $z$ to check.
From $(7)$ we see that we have only finitely many $x$ and $y$ to check.

I did this by using a small program and found out that $(7,12,7)$ and $12,7,7)$ are the only solutions. I think deeper investigations will show that this can be done without a program.

So if you consider $z \pmod 3$ one will see that $z\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.
Becasue if $z\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $\frac{2166}{12+z} \pmod 3$ is not $0$, but all other terms in $(7)$ are $0\mod 3$.  This is a contradiction.
If $z \not\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $(7)$ results in
$$0\equiv z^2-z\tag 8$$
from which $z\equiv 1\pmod 3$ follows.

So the only possible values for $z+12$ are $1,-2,19,19^2,-2\cdot 19, -2\cdot 19^2$.

Th OP is only in positive integer solutions. In this case $z+12$ can only be $19$ or $19^2$.